# ROR: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, argument-error

On the following piece of code

```
def initialize(clause)
      clause =~ /^([\w\_\.]+)(->'\w+')?_(desc|asc)$|^([\w\_\.]+->>'[\w\_]+')(->'\w+')?_(desc|asc)$/
      @column = $1 || $4
      @op = $2 || $5
      @order = $3 || $6
      @field = [@column, @op].compact.join
    end
```

I am getting the following error

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
  config/initializers/order_clause.rb:5:in `initialize'
```

Does anyone knows how to resolve it? Please Help!

**EDIT** - I am adding the full code for more clarification.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class OrderClause
    attr_reader :field, :order

    def initialize(clause)
      clause =~ /^([\w\_\.]+)(->'\w+')?_(desc|asc)$|^([\w\_\.]+->>'[\w\_]+')(->'\w+')?_(desc|asc)$/
      @column = $1 || $4
      @op = $2 || $5
      @order = $3 || $6
      @field = [@column, @op].compact.join
    end

    def valid?
      @field.present? && @order.present?
    end

    def to_sql(active_admin_config)
      table = column_in_table?(active_admin_config.resource_column_names, @column) ? active_admin_config.resource_table_name : nil
      if json_column?(@column)
        table_column = (@column =~ /\./) ? @column : [table, @column].compact.join(".")
        ['(', table_column, @op, ' ',')::numeric ', @order].compact.join
      else
        table_column = (@column =~ /\./) ? @column : [table, active_admin_config.resource_quoted_column_name(@column)].compact.join(".")
        [table_column, @op, ' ', @order].compact.join
      end
    end

    private

    def json_column?(column)
      column.include?('->>')
    end

    def column_in_table?(names, column)
      column = json_column?(column) ? column.split('->>')[0].strip : column
      names.include?(column)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How're you creating a new instance of that class?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I have added the code. You can take a look.

Comment: What's in the file config/initializers/order_clause.rb line number 5? Or is the one you just added?

Comment: @SebastianPalma It is pointing to line number 5 which is `def initialize(clause)`

Comment: So you have to see where that class is being instantiated, as I see in your question there's no info about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `activeadmin` gem instantiates the `ActiveAdmin::OrderClause` class with a couple of arguments (`active_admin_config` and `order`) as you can see [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/3dcb1834620f38f73ac5c1f550f37986d486f29c/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L205) and [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/3dcb1834620f38f73ac5c1f550f37986d486f29c/lib/active_admin/views/components/table_for.rb#L113). Fix the `initialize` method arguments.

```rb
def initialize(active_admin_config, clause)
  # ... 
end
```

You should also remove the `active_admin_config` argument from the `to_sql` method since it is called with no arguments. You can set `@active_admin_config` in the `initialize` method and add `:active_admin_config` to the `attr_reader` call to use in the `to_sql` method.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class OrderClause
    attr_reader :field, :order, :active_admin_config

    def initialize(active_admin_config, clause)
      @active_admin_config = active_admin_config
      # rest of the code
    end

    def to_sql
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

I would recommend you create a `CustomOrderClause` class that inherits from the gem's `ActiveAdmin::OrderClause` class and only override the necessary methods. You can then use `config.order_clause = CustomOrderClause` when configuring activeadmin in an initializer.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. The actual error is ```wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)``` at def to_sql(active_admin_config)

Comment: @User You're welcome. I also updated the answer on how to customize the order clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override `ActiveAdmin::OrderClause` I think and if you see ActivAdmin's code you will find this:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class OrderClause
    attr_reader :field, :order, :active_admin_config

    def initialize(active_admin_config, clause)
      clause =~ /^([\w\.]+)(->'\w+')?_(desc|asc)$/
      @column = $1
      @op = $2
      @order = $3
      @active_admin_config = active_admin_config
      @field = [@column, @op].compact.join
    end
```

This means wherever it is initialized it would be initialized with two arguments because their constructor accepts that. So you will have to change the `initialize` method in your code to accept two arguments or pass only one argument from wherever it is being called which would be tedious to do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than overwriting the entire class you should be able to use [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-prepend) to just alter the functionality you are interested in altering without having to worry about the rest of the implementation. e.g.

```
module OrderClauseExtension 
  def initialize(active_admin_config, clause)
      super
      if field.empty?
        clause =~ /^([\w\_\.]+->>'[\w\_]+')(->'\w+')?_(desc|asc)$/
        @column = $1 
        @op = $2 
        @order = $3
        @field = [@column, @op].compact.join
      end
  end
end 

ActiveAdmin::OrderClause.prepend(OrderClauseExtension)
```

This will try the original implementation first and use your implementation as a fallback in the event that the `field` attribute results in an empty `String` which would be the case in `[nil,nil].compact.join #=> ""`

All the rest of the functionality contained in this class will remain unchanged and you will not have to worry about any changes to the gem itself (unless the initialize method and/or attributes assigned here change)

You can place this file in `config/initializers`.